# Spring data rest base path is loosing it's @RepositoryRestResource links after running an unkown period of time

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have a very strange behavior since I updated to Spring Boot v2.2.6-RELEASE.
My spring data rest base path (/api/v1) is loosing it's @RepositoryRestResource links. Custom links are still available.

After a server restart I got:
[image]

After an unkown period of time (2-3 days) I got:
[image]

My base path it customized this way:

```
@Bean
public RepresentationModelProcessor<RepositoryLinksResource> globalLinkProcessor() {

    // do not replace with lambda!!!
    return new RepresentationModelProcessor<RepositoryLinksResource>() {

        @Override
        public RepositoryLinksResource process(final RepositoryLinksResource repositoryLinksResource) {

            repositoryLinksResource.add(linkHelper.newLinkFromMethodInvocation(
                    WebMvcLinkBuilder.methodOn(FileProcessorController.class).status(), "fileProcessor"));

            repositoryLinksResource.add(linkHelper.newLinkFromMethodInvocation(
                    WebMvcLinkBuilder.methodOn(CurrentUserController.class).whoAmI(), "whoAmI"));

            repositoryLinksResource.add(linkHelper.newLinkFromMethodInvocation(
                    WebMvcLinkBuilder.methodOn(UserController.class).listOperations(), "users"));

            repositoryLinksResource.add(linkHelper.newLinkFromMethodInvocation(
                    WebMvcLinkBuilder.methodOn(StatisticController.class).listOperations(), "statistics"));

            return repositoryLinksResource;
        }
    };
}
```

There is NO exception in any log output. When I debug from my local machine everything is fine. I am not getting any hands on it. Can anyone help here?

Thanks for reading,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

An update to Spring Boot v2.3.0-RELEASE solved the problem. (until now)